# How to scrape HTML with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote a script what scrape a website and put the content into a word file.
I have a problem because like the code below there is two paragraph and I want to get the text from both paragraphs but separately.
So my quiestion is: Is there any way to search for only the paragraphs between two specific h2 class or how to solve this?

HTML:

```
<h2 class="pt-3" id="mitigation">Mitigation</h2>
<p>Access tokens are an integral part of the security system within Windows and cannot be turned off. However, an attacker must already have administrator level access on the local system to make full use of this technique; be sure to restrict users and accounts to the least privileges they require to do their job.</p><p>Any user can also spoof access tokens if they have legitimate credentials. Follow mitigation guidelines for preventing adversary use of <a href="/techniques/T1078">Valid Accounts</a>. Limit permissions so that users and user groups cannot create tokens. This setting should be defined for the local system account only. GPO: Computer Configuration &gt; [Policies] &gt; Windows Settings &gt; Security Settings &gt; Local Policies &gt; User Rights Assignment: Create a token object. <span  id="scite-ref-19-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft Create Token"><sup><a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/device-security/security-policy-settings/create-a-token-object" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="18" aria-describedby="qtip-18">[19]</a></sup></span> Also define who can create a process level token to only the local and network service through GPO: Computer Configuration &gt; [Policies] &gt; Windows Settings &gt; Security Settings &gt; Local Policies &gt; User Rights Assignment: Replace a process level token. <span  id="scite-ref-20-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft Replace Process Token"><sup><a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/device-security/security-policy-settings/replace-a-process-level-token" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="19" aria-describedby="qtip-19">[20]</a></sup></span></p><p>Also limit opportunities for adversaries to increase privileges by limiting Privilege Escalation opportunities.</p>
<h2 class="pt-3" id="detection">Detection</h2>
<p>If an adversary is using a standard command-line shell, analysts can detect token manipulation by auditing command-line activity. Specifically, analysts should look for use of the <code>runas</code> command. Detailed command-line logging is not enabled by default in Windows. <span  id="scite-ref-21-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft Command-line Logging"><sup><a href="https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-ds/manage/component-updates/command-line-process-auditing" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="20" aria-describedby="qtip-20">[21]</a></sup></span></p><p>If an adversary is using a payload that calls the Windows token APIs directly, analysts can detect token manipulation only through careful analysis of user network activity, examination of running processes, and correlation with other endpoint and network behavior. </p><p>There are many Windows API calls a payload can take advantage of to manipulate access tokens (e.g., <code>LogonUser</code> <span  id="scite-ref-22-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft LogonUser"><sup><a href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="21" aria-describedby="qtip-21">[22]</a></sup></span>, <code>DuplicateTokenEx</code> <span  id="scite-ref-23-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft DuplicateTokenEx"><sup><a href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446617(v=vs.85).aspx" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="22" aria-describedby="qtip-22">[23]</a></sup></span>, and <code>ImpersonateLoggedOnUser</code> <span  id="scite-ref-24-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft ImpersonateLoggedOnUser"><sup><a href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612(v=vs.85).aspx" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="23" aria-describedby="qtip-23">[24]</a></sup></span>). Please see the referenced Windows API pages for more information.</p><p>Query systems for process and thread token information and look for inconsistencies such as user owns processes impersonating the local SYSTEM account. <span  id="scite-ref-3-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="BlackHat Atkinson Winchester Token Manipulation"><sup><a href="https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-17/materials/eu-17-Atkinson-A-Process-Is-No-One-Hunting-For-Token-Manipulation.pdf" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="2" aria-describedby="qtip-2">[3]</a></sup></span></p>
```

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from docx import Document

def linkgenerator_getlink():
   link = "https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/"
    for i in range(1001, 1224):
        fullurl = link + "T" + str(i) + "/"
        source = requests.get(fullurl).text
        time.sleep(15)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

        document = Document()
        document.add_heading(soup.find('h1').text.strip().encode("UTF-8"), 0)

        p = soup.findAll("p")
        for x in p:
            paragraphs = unicode(x.text)
            p1 = document.add_paragraph(paragraphs)
        document.save('C:\\Users\XXX\Desktop\\script\\' + (str("T%s.docx") % str(i)))
        print "========== %s-es szamu doksi is ready ==========" % i



linkgenerator_getlink()
```

Comment: How did you try? Show us your current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as you specifically know the tags, you can just specifically put those in. otherwise, you may need to create variables to iterate through. But you'll have a better idea of that since you know what the html looks like.

```
import bs4

r = '''<h2 class="pt-3" id="mitigation">Mitigation</h2>
        <p>Access tokens are an integral part of the security system within Windows and cannot be turned off. However, an attacker must already have administrator level access on the local system to make full use of this technique; be sure to restrict users and accounts to the least privileges they require to do their job.</p><p>Any user can also spoof access tokens if they have legitimate credentials. Follow mitigation guidelines for preventing adversary use of <a href="/techniques/T1078">Valid Accounts</a>. Limit permissions so that users and user groups cannot create tokens. This setting should be defined for the local system account only. GPO: Computer Configuration &gt; [Policies] &gt; Windows Settings &gt; Security Settings &gt; Local Policies &gt; User Rights Assignment: Create a token object. <span  id="scite-ref-19-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft Create Token"><sup><a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/device-security/security-policy-settings/create-a-token-object" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="18" aria-describedby="qtip-18">[19]</a></sup></span> Also define who can create a process level token to only the local and network service through GPO: Computer Configuration &gt; [Policies] &gt; Windows Settings &gt; Security Settings &gt; Local Policies &gt; User Rights Assignment: Replace a process level token. <span  id="scite-ref-20-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft Replace Process Token"><sup><a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/device-security/security-policy-settings/replace-a-process-level-token" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="19" aria-describedby="qtip-19">[20]</a></sup></span></p><p>Also limit opportunities for adversaries to increase privileges by limiting Privilege Escalation opportunities.</p>
        <h2 class="pt-3" id="detection">Detection</h2>
        <p>If an adversary is using a standard command-line shell, analysts can detect token manipulation by auditing command-line activity. Specifically, analysts should look for use of the <code>runas</code> command. Detailed command-line logging is not enabled by default in Windows. <span  id="scite-ref-21-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft Command-line Logging"><sup><a href="https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-ds/manage/component-updates/command-line-process-auditing" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="20" aria-describedby="qtip-20">[21]</a></sup></span></p><p>If an adversary is using a payload that calls the Windows token APIs directly, analysts can detect token manipulation only through careful analysis of user network activity, examination of running processes, and correlation with other endpoint and network behavior. </p><p>There are many Windows API calls a payload can take advantage of to manipulate access tokens (e.g., <code>LogonUser</code> <span  id="scite-ref-22-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft LogonUser"><sup><a href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="21" aria-describedby="qtip-21">[22]</a></sup></span>, <code>DuplicateTokenEx</code> <span  id="scite-ref-23-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft DuplicateTokenEx"><sup><a href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446617(v=vs.85).aspx" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="22" aria-describedby="qtip-22">[23]</a></sup></span>, and <code>ImpersonateLoggedOnUser</code> <span  id="scite-ref-24-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft ImpersonateLoggedOnUser"><sup><a href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612(v=vs.85).aspx" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="23" aria-describedby="qtip-23">[24]</a></sup></span>). Please see the referenced Windows API pages for more information.</p><p>Query systems for process and thread token information and look for inconsistencies such as user owns processes impersonating the local SYSTEM account. <span  id="scite-ref-3-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="BlackHat Atkinson Winchester Token Manipulation"><sup><a href="https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-17/materials/eu-17-Atkinson-A-Process-Is-No-One-Hunting-For-Token-Manipulation.pdf" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="2" aria-describedby="qtip-2">[3]</a></sup></span></p>'''


html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r)

# assuming the 1st paragraph you want is id="mitigation"
# find that, then grab the next sibling
para_1 = html.find('h2', {'id':'mitigation'})
p1 = para_1.find_next_sibling('p').text

para_2 = html.find('h2', {'id':'detection'})
p2 = para_2.find_next_sibling('p').text
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives the inside text of the `<p>` tag next to all `<h2>` tags with classes as specified:

```
import bs4 as bs

content = """<h2 class="pt-3" id="mitigation">Mitigation</h2>
<p>Access tokens are an integral part of the security system within Windows and cannot be turned off. However, an attacker must already have administrator level access on the local system to make full use of this technique; be sure to restrict users and accounts to the least privileges they require to do their job.</p><p>Any user can also spoof access tokens if they have legitimate credentials. Follow mitigation guidelines for preventing adversary use of <a href="/techniques/T1078">Valid Accounts</a>. Limit permissions so that users and user groups cannot create tokens. This setting should be defined for the local system account only. GPO: Computer Configuration &gt; [Policies] &gt; Windows Settings &gt; Security Settings &gt; Local Policies &gt; User Rights Assignment: Create a token object. <span  id="scite-ref-19-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft Create Token"><sup><a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/device-security/security-policy-settings/create-a-token-object" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="18" aria-describedby="qtip-18">[19]</a></sup></span> Also define who can create a process level token to only the local and network service through GPO: Computer Configuration &gt; [Policies] &gt; Windows Settings &gt; Security Settings &gt; Local Policies &gt; User Rights Assignment: Replace a process level token. <span  id="scite-ref-20-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft Replace Process Token"><sup><a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/device-security/security-policy-settings/replace-a-process-level-token" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="19" aria-describedby="qtip-19">[20]</a></sup></span></p><p>Also limit opportunities for adversaries to increase privileges by limiting Privilege Escalation opportunities.</p>
<h2 class="pt-3" id="detection">Detection</h2>
<p>If an adversary is using a standard command-line shell, analysts can detect token manipulation by auditing command-line activity. Specifically, analysts should look for use of the <code>runas</code> command. Detailed command-line logging is not enabled by default in Windows. <span  id="scite-ref-21-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft Command-line Logging"><sup><a href="https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-ds/manage/component-updates/command-line-process-auditing" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="20" aria-describedby="qtip-20">[21]</a></sup></span></p><p>If an adversary is using a payload that calls the Windows token APIs directly, analysts can detect token manipulation only through careful analysis of user network activity, examination of running processes, and correlation with other endpoint and network behavior. </p><p>There are many Windows API calls a payload can take advantage of to manipulate access tokens (e.g., <code>LogonUser</code> <span  id="scite-ref-22-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft LogonUser"><sup><a href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="21" aria-describedby="qtip-21">[22]</a></sup></span>, <code>DuplicateTokenEx</code> <span  id="scite-ref-23-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft DuplicateTokenEx"><sup><a href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446617(v=vs.85).aspx" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="22" aria-describedby="qtip-22">[23]</a></sup></span>, and <code>ImpersonateLoggedOnUser</code> <span  id="scite-ref-24-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="Microsoft ImpersonateLoggedOnUser"><sup><a href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612(v=vs.85).aspx" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="23" aria-describedby="qtip-23">[24]</a></sup></span>). Please see the referenced Windows API pages for more information.</p><p>Query systems for process and thread token information and look for inconsistencies such as user owns processes impersonating the local SYSTEM account. <span  id="scite-ref-3-a" class="scite-citeref-number" data-reference="BlackHat Atkinson Winchester Token Manipulation"><sup><a href="https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-17/materials/eu-17-Atkinson-A-Process-Is-No-One-Hunting-For-Token-Manipulation.pdf" target="_blank" data-hasqtip="2" aria-describedby="qtip-2">[3]</a></sup></span></p>"""

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")

for h2_tag in soup('h2', {'class': 'pt-3'}):
    print(h2_tag.next_sibling.next_sibling.text)
    print("") # line of separation after each paragragh
```

Output:

```
Access tokens are an integral part of the security system within Windows and cannot be turned off. However, an attacker must already have administrator level access on the local system to make full use of this technique; be sure to restrict users and accounts to the least privileges they require to do their job.

If an adversary is using a standard command-line shell, analysts can detect token manipulation by auditing command-line activity. Specifically, analysts should look for use of the runas command. Detailed command-line logging is not enabled by default in Windows. [21]
```